# ChartJS do not render any legend if the label is falsy

Tags: chart.js

I am using ChartJS 2.4 and I want to predefine lots of settings in the datasets already. But use an empty data array and an undefined label. Now I want to stop ChartJS from rendering the legend which is then shown as "null" or "undefined". Later I am setting a proper label and start to push data to the dataSet and finally call update() on the chart which works fine.

Here is a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du9afk1u/8/) with this code:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [],
        }
    ]
};

var myLineChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
    data: data
});


setTimeout(function(){
  data.datasets[0].label = "The Label"
  data.datasets[0].data.push(10, 20)
    myLineChart.update()
}, 2000)
```

I have tried to overwrite generateLabels but I had no luck with that. And the setting dateaset.hidden only strikes through the legend if true but not really "hides".

EDIT 1: On the other hand setting `options.legend.display` to false hides all the legends and for ever, this is also not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us create a plugin that, at the start of every update, decides whether to display the legend or not based on whether the label of the first dataset is (respectively) defined or not. The `autoDisplayLegend` chart option enables the plugin, if set to `true`.

A working fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/du9afk1u/10/). The code is also available below.

```js
var autoDisplayLegendPlugin = {
  // Called at start of update.
  beforeUpdate: function(chartInstance) {
    if (chartInstance.options.autoDisplayLegend) {
      // The first (and, assuming, only) dataset.
      var dataset = chartInstance.data.datasets[0];
      if (dataset.label)
        chartInstance.options.legend.display = true;
      else
        chartInstance.options.legend.display = false;
    }
  }
};

Chart.pluginService.register(autoDisplayLegendPlugin);

var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 5,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [],
  }]
};

var myLineChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: data,
  options: {
    // Option to auto display the legend.
    autoDisplayLegend: true
  }
});


setTimeout(function() {
  data.datasets[0].label = "The Label"
  data.datasets[0].data.push(10, 20)
  myLineChart.update()
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: but this hides all of them and for ever - not just as long as the label is null

Comment: So, you want a fully automatic way to show the legend if and only if the dataset's label is defined?

Comment: exactly or lets say as automated as possible

Comment: Check out a plugin-based approach.

Comment: That's interesting thx. But this only works if I have only one dataset right? I want to style lots in advance, could we hook in every legend as well using a plugins approach?

Comment: There is a single legend for all datasets. This will work for more datasets, but the first dataset will determine whether the legend is displayed. Are you talking about hiding a legend item if the dataset that corresponds to this legend item does not have a label defined?

Comment: Ah I see so yes, I actually want to render a legend item if the label is truthy and not render this label item  otherwise

Comment: Also check https://jsfiddle.net/du9afk1u/12/ (this example demonstrates that the dataset labels alone decide whether the corresponding legend items, as well as the legend, are displayed) before the answer update, which will happen tomorrow.

Comment: the splice did not work correctly I have used a filter: https://jsfiddle.net/du9afk1u/13/ but this is pretty cool. thx, yes please update the answer as well

Comment: It just occurred to me that the splice would not work correctly, because after the first deletion the indices would not be valid anymore. I will update it tomorrow. ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can delete the dataset so the legend will not display:

```
var autoDisplayLegendPlugin = {

beforeUpdate: function(chartInstance) {

if (chartInstance.canvas.id == 'chart6') {
  // The first (and, assuming, only) dataset.
  var dataset = chartInstance.data.datasets[2];
  if (dataset.data.length != 0){ // delete only if there is no data in dataset
    console.log(chartInstance);
    chartInstance.options.legend.display = true;

  }
  else{
    chartInstance.options.legend.display = true;
    chartInstance.data.datasets.pop(); // if is the last datasets you don't want the legend to appear
  }
}
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the labels and use that to remove a falsy text

```js
const data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    fill: false,
    lineTension: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
    borderDash: [],
    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
    pointRadius: 5,
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    data: [],
  }]
};

const myLineChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (legendItem) => (!!legendItem.text)
        }
      }
    }
  }
});


setTimeout(function() {
  data.datasets[0].label = "The Label"
  data.datasets[0].data.push(10, 20)
  myLineChart.update()
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

The main reason is ,it's showing

> undefined

because you haven't defined the label property for your datasets.

```
 datasets: [{ 
  data: [1,2,6,3,8,9,5],
  label:'your label',
  borderColor: "red",
  fill: false
}]
```